# Audio playback from in-memory data for Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, audio

Is there a BlackBerry API that provides low-level audio access?  Preferably for Blackberry OS 4.6.0 but 6.0.0 is OK too.  The [Audio](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.6.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/Audio.html) class plays from files, whereas I need to be able to create audio in-memory, as an array of integers, and pass it to the API for playback.

Answer (score 2):

You could probably create your own [DataSource](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/javax/microedition/media/protocol/DataSource.html)/[SourceStream](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/javax/microedition/media/protocol/SourceStream.html) and create the sound data in WAV format in-memory, then use [Manager](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/javax/microedition/media/Manager.html) to create a [Player](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/javax/microedition/media/Player.html) and play it.